# How to update a Column in all rows with single query - Android Room Database

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am trying to update a column in `Room` database android which is associated with all rows.

My condition is i have a column called `isActive` which is a `boolean` column if a row contains `true` value for this column all other row should have `false`

This is what i have tried but it clearly updates a single row

```
@Query("UPDATE ADDRESS SET isActive = (CASE WHEN isActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE addressId = :addressId")
```

Only the row I'm pointing to with primary key is getting updated i want all rows expect that row to update

Even if the column is already true it should be changed to false

How do I solve this?

Comment: First make all rows inactive. Then use another query to active only the selected addressId.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem

This is what i have tried to replace the query with

***note: we don't need 2 queries to achieve this***

**Answer:**

```
@Query("UPDATE ADDRESS SET isActive = CASE addressId WHEN :addressId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
```

by including addressId in CASE have solved my problem.

Hope this might help someone!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all the rows, then you have to remove where condition.

Comment: if i remove the condition how will it update the row currently i want to be active and all others to not active (note there might be some address field with already active status)

Comment: Ok. You cannot achieve the result by using only one query. You have to apply two queries. 1) Update all row to set as inactive 2) Update selected row to active by using addressID.